# vim command-line snippets possible?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to define and use snippets on the vim command-line? For example, when I want to select a portion of text I want to replace a string of text within, excluding the rest of the line, I have to change:

```
:'<,'>
```

to

```
:%s\%VsPat/rPat/g
```

which once in awhile might be alright, but lately I find myself performing this kind of s/S/R/ often enough to make it a PITA; yet still more efficient than making each change in the selection manually.

Actually there are quite a few regular editing command I use in VIM that would increase my efficiency if I could tie them to a snippet somehow. So is there any way to use snippets at vim command-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just going on with your substitution without changing anything?

```
:'<,'>s/\%VsPat/rPat/g
```

Or using a visual mode mapping?

```
xnoremap <key> :s/\%V/g<left><left>
```

Comment: well now, that works. I don't know why I never tried :'<,'>s/\%VsPat/rPat/g instead of :%s\%VsPat/rPat/g before. That will sure streamline things a bit for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is build-in feature `cnoreabbrev` it is simple replacement, so if you define it for example

```
:cnoreabbrev ss %s\%VsPat/rPat/g
```

then when you type `:ss` and press `<space>`, it will automatically replace `ss` with following

```
:%s\%VsPat/rPat/g
```

Check it out,  it should solve at least half of your problems :-)

Comment: I can be real slow at seeing the whole picture, so excuse me if I am missing something obvious here; but if sPat/rPat are not static search/replace patterns then would it make sense to hard wire them to a shortcut? However, I can definitely see where this might well cut down on the many static commands I do routinely run from the ved cli. So I will check it out. Thanks.